# How can I script schtasks so it doesn't need a password?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-vista, schtasks

I'm trying to install some software using a batch script and using schtasks to start a service every day at midnight.

The script works fine, but it prompts for a password, which causes the script to hang. I've tried using the '/RU "user" /RP ""' flags, which seemed to work in XP, but not under Vista.

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 4):

If you understand the security implications*, you could run tasks with the local System account without a password.

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN MyTask /TR "C:\MyTask.bat" /SC ONSTART /RU SYSTEM
SCHTASKS /Run /TN MyTask
```

This also works through the GUI, just enter SYSTEM as the user name and leave the password field blank.

*The biggest security risk would be someone changing the script or executable your scheduled task is pointed at. Be sure to set the file permissions accordingly.

Comment: You can further read about it here: http://technomosh.blogspot.com/2008/12/windows-scheduling-tip.html

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried /u and /p (without the R)?

From the help file:

> /U username
>      Specifies the user context under which the command should execute.
>   /P password
>      Specifies the password for the given user context.

Alternatively you could try using this utility to create a run as command for your task:
http://www.robotronic.de/runasspc/