# Automatically Restarting Windows Service Depending on Certain Time Interval

Tags: windows, windows-service

Is there anyway, on Windows machine, to automatically restart a certain windows service?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could create a scheduled task restarting the service with `net stop` and `net start`.

Answer (score 5):

The quick and dirty way would be to setup a scheduled task to run the following command line.

```
sc.exe stop <serviceName> && sc.exe start <serviceName>
```

To create this scheduled task to run every midnight via the command line:

```
SCHTASKS /Create /TN "Restart Service"  /TR "sc.exe stop <serviceName> && sc.exe start <serviceName>" /SC DAILY /ST 00:00 /RU SYSTEM /F
```

You could of course add far more intelligence and logging to this process. Maybe even write a full [Powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powershell) script around the [Get-Service](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347591.aspx) CMDLet. If you would rather not create a separate local account (preferred) to run this scheduled task, you can use the account ['System' without a password](https://serverfault.com/questions/43539/43546#43546).

- [SC](http://ss64.com/nt/sc.html)
- [SCHTASKS](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)
- [Get-Service](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powershell)

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet would be to use something like Service Hawk.  It has a feature built-in that allows you to restart services automatically on a user-defined schedule.